# Every subgroup of a group is normal

Tags: group-theory

It is known that every subgroup of an abelian group is normal . Does there exist a non-abelian group such that every subgroup of the group is normal ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes. these groups are called hamiltonian, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_group
the most popular example would be quaternions